# how to test Windows service

Tags: windows-services

i have a windows service which is writen in vb.net 
in order to be sure about the performance 
i want to test it before instalation 
how can i do the job in vs2010
is there any special tool in vs2010 or an extension

any idea ?

Regards,

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to learn on how to do performance testing, or do you just want to learn how to debug windows services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already told you in my answer to your other question - you might want to check out some "hybrid" approaches, that would allow you to write your code as a command-line app first (which can be easily debugged), and once it works okay, you can then install it as a service:

- [HybridService: Easily Switch Between Console Application and Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HybridService.aspx)
- [Hybrid Windows Service](http://hws.codeplex.com/)
- [TopShelf - a service-construction helper for .NET](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Comment: i want to test it befor installation

Comment: @dav: yes, that's what I keep saying - by using a hybrid, you can run your code as a console app and easily debug it - **BEFORE** any installation!!

Comment: that was great man .specialy the acode project article .it works.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.80).aspx this link also  helped me .